# Failed to enable SMBus PCI Device and Bluetooth Error

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, dell, smbus

Just after powering up my laptop, the following message comes:

````
[   1.329900]i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: Failed to enable SMBus PCI device (-16)```
/dev/sda3: clean, 223082/30498816 files, 5175829/121964544 blocks
[   22.552755] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected eent for opcode 0xfc2f
````

I'm not sure what this error is or why, but after a few seconds, my Ubuntu runs properly. The only thing is it's taking a lot of time to boot cause of these errors.

Please help fix these errors. I'm currently on Dell Latitude 3340.

Answer (score 1):

These messages shouldn't affect performance. There is no easy way to remove them at boot time as far as I know.

If the system works well, I would ignore them.

Comment: Thank You @Pilot6
But can you please help in fixing these issues as there are indeed (I suppose) some issues that I am facing due to these errors

Comment: There are no "issues" because of these errors. You can ask a new question about any problems you have. The only issue can be with Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this operation and it works for me.

```bash
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

and change this line to disable i801_smbus feature:

```bash
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i2c-i801.disable_features=0x10 quiet splash"
```

Then do `sudo update-grub` .